# LAG function and GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this,

```
 event_id |          date          
----------+------------------------
  1703702 | 2013-06-25 07:50:57-04
  3197588 | 2013-06-25 07:51:57-04
 60894420 | 2013-06-25 07:52:57-04
 60894420 | 2013-06-25 07:53:57-04
   183503 | 2013-06-25 07:54:57-04
 63116743 | 2013-06-25 07:55:57-04
 63110451 | 2013-06-25 07:56:57-04
 63116743 | 2013-06-25 07:57:57-04
 63116743 | 2013-06-25 07:58:57-04
```

I'd like to apply the lag function but also a group by so I can find the time intervals between any particular event_id.

I'd like something like this:

```
SELECT event_id, difference
FROM ( 
  SELECT event_id, date - lag(date) over (order by date) as
  difference FROM table GROUP BY event_id
) t;
```

I cannot however use GROUP BY with the LAG function. I'd like a result similar to the following:

```
63116743, {120, 60}
60894420, {60}
...
...
```

So there was a 120s and 60s window between the events for the first id, and a 60s window for the second id.

Is there a way to do this? The output format is not too important as long as I can get it into an array in the end. I'm using Postgres 9.1

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what the output means. 120? 60? of what? it doesn't appear to come from the data you showed.

Comment: The sub-select in your question isn't adding anything to the query - you are effectively doing a `SELECT *` from it, which is the same as just running the inner query.

Comment: @depesz It's an interval expressed in seconds: 120s between '2013-06-25 07:55:57-04' and '2013-06-25 07:57:57-04', then 60s between that and '2013-06-25 07:58:57-04', comparing just the events with the same ID.

Comment: Thanks for the good question - Pg version, sample data, expected results.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
WITH diffs as (
    SELECT
        event_id,
        date - lag(date) over (partition BY event_id ORDER BY date) as difference
    FROM
        TABLE
)
SELECT
    event_id,
    array_agg( difference ) as all_diffs
FROM
    diffs
GROUP BY event_id;
```

Should work.

Comment: And here's a SQLFiddle to prove it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c22fc/4 (`array_agg` seems to break SQLFiddle for some reason, so I used `string_agg` to check the result)

Comment: Oh, and to express in seconds, `EXTRACT('epoch' FROM ...)`: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c22fc/6

Comment: I misunderstood the question and didn't include the crucial `PARTITION BY`; I was preparing the SQLFiddle to figure it out, but you beat me to it :)