# Postgresql: LAG until a row with a certain value is found, and return that value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset containing emails from customers.

One of the columns is Type. In Type exists a value 'Duplicate Case' which flags that a customer has just sent us a barrage of emails about the same topic. We only reply to the original and close all other cases as duplicates. But what I want to do, is get the type of the original email.

I want to be able to create the column Original Type:

[image]

There generally aren't more than 5 duplicates of a cases per customers.I would like to add logic which only returns results **where duplicate cases are 24 hours older than the original**

I have this awful piece of code:

```
CASE
 WHEN type = 'Duplicate Case'
 AND LAG(type,4) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC) = 'Duplicate Case'
  THEN LAG(type,5) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC)

 WHEN type = 'Duplicate Case'
 AND LAG(type,3) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC) = 'Duplicate Case'
  THEN LAG(type,4) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC)

 WHEN type = 'Duplicate Case'
 AND LAG(type,2) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC) = 'Duplicate Case'
  THEN LAG(type,3) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC)

WHEN LAG(type) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC) = 'Duplicate Case'
AND type = 'Duplicate Case'
  THEN LAG(type,2) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC)

WHEN type = 'Duplicate Case'
  THEN LAG(type) OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_code ORDER BY case_number ASC)
    END AS original_type
```

And this gives me sort of what I want:

[image]

But how can I add a time logic? I want to put in Type only from the first non-duplicate if this duplicate was created less than 24 hours before the original type?

Comment: I don't think you need `LAG` for this. You could create a (temp) table which isolates each unique case with an ID. I imagine the logic would be along the lines of `GROUP BY on Created Date, Customer ID and Type WHERE Type <> 'Duplicated Case'`. Then join this table to the original on the newly created ID with your time logic.

Comment: Oh, your ID logic is already in the `PARTITION BY` so create a unique ID for each partition.

Comment: I agree with ruaridh, his approach is much cleaner,. but if u stick to ur use of lag, take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301816/lag-function-and-group-by. don't use array_agg() and adept the group by accordingly to include the date

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying and I believe you're right, since I don't need to code for a fixed n number of duplicated records. What i've done is create a temp table with a column "original type", then I run a query that updates this column where the type is 'duplicate' with the customers latest non-duplicate case type. I'll update this post with the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need to do here is create a temporary table with a blank field, then update this blank field later on with some criteria:

```
/* Main table */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cases;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cases AS
SELECT
created_date,
type,
CASE WHEN type = 'Duplicate Case'
  THEN CAST('Unknown' AS VARCHAR(40))
  ELSE type END AS original_type,
 CAST('' AS VARCHAR(40)) AS original_case_number,
client_code,
case_number
FROM case
 ORDER BY c.client_code DESC, case_number DESC;

/* Append previous case data */

UPDATE cases
SET original_case_number = prev_case_number
FROM
(
    SELECT
      a.case_number,
      MAX(b.case_number) AS prev_case_number
      FROM cases a
     LEFT JOIN cases b ON a.client_code = b.client_code
     AND b.created_date BETWEEN a.created_date - INTERVAL '48 hour' AND 
     a.created_date + INTERVAL '1 second'
     AND b.type <> 'Duplicate Case'
     AND a.type = 'Duplicate Case'
     GROUP BY 1
 ) prev
  WHERE cases.case_number = prev.case_number;

UPDATE cases
SET original_type = b.type
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM cases) b
  WHERE cases.original_case_number = b.case_number;
```

SELECT * FROM cases